# I got this error while building a blockchain

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node, blockchain

Encountered the following error while simulating a network when running the command:

> ./target/release/node-template purge-chain --base-path /tmp/alice
> --chain local

I got error indicating

> /tmp/alice/chains/local_testnet/db/full did not
> exist.

Can we proceed with next step in the  substrate documentation without purging the old chain data.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is not an error, more of an indication.

If you really want to check you can manually look in those folders:

```
ls /tmpl/alice/chains/local_testnet/db
ls /tmpl/alice/chains/local_testnet
ls /tmpl/alice/chains
ls /tmp/alice
ls /tmp
```

You probably do not see anything there because you ran your Substrate blockchain using `--dev` or `--tmp` which wipes the db after you shutdown the running blockchain.

```
--tmp
Run a temporary node. A temporary directory will be created to store the configuration and will be deleted at the end of the process. Note: the directory is random per process execution. 
This directory is used as base path which includes: database, node key and keystore. 
When `--dev` is given and no explicit `--base-path`, this option is implied
```

Comment: Can we proceed with next steps without purging the old chain data, or is that step neccessary to purge that.

Comment: Which documentation/steps are you referring to?

Comment: Substrate documentation

Comment: I am guessing you're following a tutorial? Do you have a link to the tutorial or steps you're referring to?

Comment: https://docs.substrate.io/quick-start/   in this documentation I'm following tutorial.

Comment: Yes so proceed to the next steps.